# Content css before option in safari not work

Tags: html, css

i have used checkbox symbol for option in select dropdown with css selector before, but in safari not work (chrome and firefox is ok).

```
option:before { content: "☐"}
option:before { content: "text"}
```

I can't understand why, i have try another tag in option but nothing.

Comment: I guess it means, safari doesn't support it

Answer (score 1):

I assume you trying to add a check symbol to the `<option>` element inside the `<select>`, right?

`<select>` doesn't support pseudo-selector and its behavior system-dependent.

Also, if you're using custom fonts - some special characters might be missing for this font. So make sure your font has all characters you need, or specify a web-safe font like in [this example](https://codepen.io/vovchisko/pen/yLVQREr?editors=1100).

[image: checks]